# How to find max value in a column in a datarow[] ?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, max, datarow, icomparable

I have a simple problem but I just don't understand any of the examples I find here or in MSDN. (I'm still new to C# and all the datasets functions).

I have a datatable "tblRoom" which its columms are "building","apartment" and "room" and they're all ints and the table's primary keys (it's a weak entity of apartment (which is weak entity of building) without other properties/columns).

I also have `DataRow[] roomCollection` that selects a specific apartment in a building with this code:

```
roomCollection = dbDataSet.tblRoom.Select("building ='"+ b_int + 
                                          "' and apartment='"+ a_int + "'");
```

All this runs fine (I guess...).
Now I want to get max value of room from this apartment (the max room number in this apartment).
I've tried to no avail these codes:

```
DataRow dr = roomCollection.Max();
int maxi = roomCollection.Max();
```

I just don't get from the tooltip what am I suppose to write in the function. It throws exceptions on either no IEnumerable or Icomparable.

What do I need to write to get the max value (int) in the room column? Anyone knows a "[something] for dummies" that explains it to an idiot because I don't understand the meaning of the errors/tooltip of what am I suppose to write in the `Max()`.

EDIT:
The tooltip suggest to enter these (shown relevants):

```
(this IEnumerable <DataRow> source):DataRow
(this IEnumerable <DataRow> source, Func<DataRow,int?> selector):int?
(this IEnumerable <DataRow> source, Func<DataRow,int> selector):int
```

I really don't get it :(

Thanks ahead,
Shay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
int roomno = roomCollection.Max (r => (int) r["room"]);
```

Comment: Ah it works! Thanks a bunch. I just have 2 more little questions:
1. Is that syntax LINQ?
2. What does it mean? var "r" gets (casted int) from ["room"]?
I really don't understand how to pass this knowledge to other problems... why "r" is the left operand of => and on the right side of it too near the column name?

Comment: the syntax is linq with delegates... the r is the first parameter of the delegate and is of type DataRow (since it comes from DataRowCollection rommCollection) and after => that is the body of the delegate representing that value used by the Max extension method to evaluate...

Comment: @Yahia . And if I want to find max value of string column? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you would want to pass the selector to `Max()` to properly identify the column you want to max..

```
int max = roomCollection.Max(dr => (int)dr["room"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since roomCollection is an array of DataRows,  `DataRow dr = roomCollection.Max();` means select the maximum DataRow from roomCollection.  But what does it mean for a DataRow to be greater than another DataRow?  In general there isn't any useful comparison which is why `.Max()` fails on you.

Technically DataRow doesn't implement `IComparable` because there is on generic useful why to compare two DataRow's and tell which one is 'larger' or 'smaller'.  However for integers there is since 2 is larger than 1.

What you need to do is pass a selector function to `Max()` to tell it what maximum value you are looking for.  So as the other answers indication you need to use:

```
int max = roomCollection.Max(dr => (int)dr["room"]);
```

This says for each DataRow select the integer value for room and get the maximum room value.

The `.Max()` function is a part of the [Linq](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) (Language Integration Query) added in .NET 3.5.  So you need to read up on that to better understand what's going on. I've found [101 Linq Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746) to be useful since it shows examples for almost every thing you would want to do.

Comment: @ShayKrainer. And if I want to find max value of string column? thanks.